# What's wrong here? accidentally referencing an existing instance instead of making a new one

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, scikit-learn, instance

I'm an [R user](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:2954547+[r]) looking to get more comfortable with Python. I wrote a kind of mini-API that makes it easy to compare different statistical models fitted to the same data, in such a way that I can pre-set all the model hyperparameters and then iterate over the different models in order to fit them.

This is the essence of what I want to do:

1. Build a wrapper class `Classifier` around a Scikit-learn [`Pipeline`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.pipeline), in turn built on one of Scikit-learn's built-in estimators, e.g. [`RandomForestClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.ensemble)
2. Create a dictionary of these un-fitted `Classifier`s, and a different dictionary of parameters to loop over
3. Iterate over both dictionaries, have each un-fitted `Classifier` generate *a new instance* of the underlying Pipeline, fit it using its `[Pipeline.fit][1]` method, and save the new, fitted Pipeline in a different dictionary

However, it seems that, instead of generating a new instance of the Pipeline, in each iteration, the same instance of the Pipeline (or maybe the underlying estimator) is being refitted. This is a problem because the `Pipeline.fit` method modifies the Pipeline (and underlying estimator) in place, so the fitted results from the previous iterations are all overwritten by the fitted results from the final iteration.

The problem is that I can't figure out where this "parent instance" is being created and how it's being referenced.

The basic setup with a reproducible example of the problem is in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/gwerbin/9ca34c1ddf16988fbe2a#file-pandas-sklearn-workflow-py) (it's a little too long to just copy and paste here). I added a print statement at the end to illustrate the issue.

Sorry if this is a little vague, but I'm not having an easy time describing it. Hopefully the issue is clear from the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `results['0']['rf']` and `results['1']['rf']` are in fact the same object. Therefore, when you fit the pipeline in your loop:

```
results = dict()
for k in features.keys():
    results[k] = dict()
    for m in classifiers.keys():
        print(len(features[k]))
        results[k][m] = classifiers[m].fit(features[k], 'species', iris)
```

You are re-fitting an already fit pipeline, losing your previous work.

To remedy this, you need to create a new instance of `Classifier` every time you fit it. One possible way to do this is to change your `classifiers` dictionary from one containing `Classifier` instances to one containing the arguments required to create a `Classifier`:

```
classifiers = {
    'rf': (RandomForestClassifier, n_estimators=100, oob_score=True, bootstrap=True),
    'ab': (AdaBoostClassifier, n_estimators=50)
}
```

Now, in your loop you should use a Python idiom known as "tuple unpacking" to unpack the arguments and create a separate `Classifier` instance for each combination

```
for k in features:
    results[k] = dict()
    for m in classifiers:
        print(len(features[k]))
        classifier = Classifier(*classifiers[m])
        results[k][m] = classifier.fit(features[k], 'species', iris)
```

Note that to iterate over the keys of a dictionary, one can simply write `for key in dct:`, as opposed to `for key in dct.keys()`.

Comment: This is what I think I thought I was doing. It's what the `make_pipe` function was for

Comment: BTW, I know this is what you meant, but it's actually `results['0']['rf'].steps[2][1]` and `id(results['1']['rf'].steps[2][1]` that are the same: `print(
    id(results['0']['rf'].steps[2][1]),
    id(results['1']['rf'].steps[2][1]),
    sep='\n'
)` versus `print(
    id(results['0']['rf']),
    id(results['1']['rf']),
    sep='\n'
)`

Comment: @ssdecontrol Ah, I see I misread your code. I thought `fit ` was modifying the `Classifier` in-place, but it is in fact calling `make_pipe`, which creates a new pipeline object, then fits that pipeline, and returns it. So you're right. The real issue is that you are creating one instance of `RandomForestClassifier` or `AdaBoostClassifier` when you initialize `Classifier`, and you're using that same instance every time you create a new pipeline with `make_pipe`. You can get around this, of course, by moving the code that creates the classifier from the `__init__` to `make_pipe`.

Comment: Yup that's exactly what I did. Thanks! This is the functionality I've been hacking together in R, but haven't been able to find a satisfying solution for.